# How to roll up duplicate observation in Python polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a data frame as-

```
my_dt = pl.DataFrame({'last_name':['mallesh','bhavik','jagarini','mallesh','jagarini'],
                  'first_name':['yamulla','vemulla','yegurla','yamulla','yegurla'],
                  'ssn':['1234','7847','0648','4567','0648']})
```

Here I would like to find out duplicates considering last_name and firs_name columns and if any duplicates found their respective ssn needs to be rolled up with semicolon(;) if SSN are not different. if SSN are also same only one SSN needs to be present.

[image]

the expected output as:

[image]

Here since mallesh yamulla is duplicated and has different SSN's they are rolled up with ';'

and in case of jagarini yegurla it has a unique SSN hence one SSN is only taken.

[image]

Added one more case:

Here on given any set of column it should rollup the unique values using ; from the remaining columns. here on last and first name, roll up should be done on both DOB and SSN.

```
my_dt = pl.DataFrame({'last_name':['mallesh','bhavik','jagarini','mallesh','jagarini'],
                  'first_name':['yamulla','vemulla','yegurla','yamulla','yegurla'],
                  'ssn':['1234','7847','0648','4567','0648'],
                  'dob':['10/11/1990','09/16/1991','01/01/1990','10/11/1990','02/14/1983']   })
```

[image]

Another case as:

```
my_dt = pl.DataFrame({'last_name':['mallesh','bhavik','jagarini','mallesh','jagarini'],
                  'first_name':['yamulla','vemulla','yegurla','yamulla','yegurla'],
                  'ssn':['1234','7847','0648','4567','0648'],
                  'dob':['10/11/1990','09/16/1991','01/01/1990','','02/14/1983']   })
```

In case of having null values in a field it should treat as empty not as a value.

";10/11/1990" it should just be "10/11/1990" for mallesh yamulla entry.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `group_by` and [`unique`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.unique.html) to remove duplicates.  From there, you can use [`arr.join`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.list.ExprListNameSpace.join.html#polars.internals.expr.list.ExprListNameSpace.join) on the resulting list.

```py
(
    my_dt
    .groupby(['last_name', 'first_name'])
    .agg([
        pl.col('ssn').unique()
    ])
    .with_column(
        pl.col('ssn').arr.join(';')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ last_name ┆ first_name ┆ ssn       │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str       │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
│ mallesh   ┆ yamulla    ┆ 4567;1234 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ bhavik    ┆ vemulla    ┆ 7847      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ jagarini  ┆ yegurla    ┆ 0648      │
└───────────┴────────────┴───────────┘
```

**Edit**: if you want to ensure that the rolled up list is sorted:

```py
(
    my_dt
    .groupby(['last_name', 'first_name'])
    .agg([
        pl.col('ssn')
        .unique()
        .sort()
    ])
    .with_column(
        pl.col('ssn')
        .arr.join(';')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ last_name ┆ first_name ┆ ssn       │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str       │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
│ jagarini  ┆ yegurla    ┆ 0648      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mallesh   ┆ yamulla    ┆ 1234;4567 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ bhavik    ┆ vemulla    ┆ 7847      │
└───────────┴────────────┴───────────┘
```

### Edit: Rolling up multiple columns

We can roll up multiple columns elegantly as follows:

```py
(
    my_dt
    .groupby(["last_name", "first_name"])
    .agg([
        pl.all().unique().sort().cast(pl.Utf8)
    ])
    .with_columns([
        pl.exclude(['last_name', 'first_name']).arr.join(";")
    ])
)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────────┬────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ last_name ┆ first_name ┆ ssn       ┆ dob                   │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---                   │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str       ┆ str                   │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ bhavik    ┆ vemulla    ┆ 7847      ┆ 1991-09-16            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ jagarini  ┆ yegurla    ┆ 0648      ┆ 1983-02-14;1990-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mallesh   ┆ yamulla    ┆ 1234;4567 ┆ 1990-10-11            │
└───────────┴────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

##### Edit: eliminating empty strings and `null` values from rollup

We can add a filter step just before the `arr.join` to filter out both `null` and empty string `""` values.

```py
(
    my_dt.groupby(["last_name", "first_name"])
    .agg([pl.all().unique().sort().cast(pl.Utf8)])
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.exclude(["last_name", "first_name"])
            .arr.eval(
                pl.element().filter(pl.element().is_not_null() & (pl.element() != ""))
            )
            .arr.join(";")
        ]
    )
)
```

Comment: OK. what if I have to roll up more than one column. here we are just working on SSN.  On given a set of column roll up should be done on the remaining columns. Example: On last and first name, it should roll up dob, ssn, address, etc etc fields.

Comment: I have added a screenshot for the above case.

Comment: One small question? : after rolling up I can't see the semicolon(;) if the column volumes are more than one: Example: SSN- ['1234',' 4567'] here it should be displayed as '1234;4567' with a string type and not a list type.

Comment: Good catch.  Let me revise the answer.

Comment: I've also added an extra `cast` expression, to make sure that `Date`/`Datetime` fields work correctly.

Comment: That's great. It works as expected

Comment: OK. how to ignore null while rolling up: example - after rolling on last and first name, DOB comes as this since there is a NULL in one row  ";10/11/1990". but here i should only get "10/11/1990". technically NULL should not be treated on rolling columns. how to filter them in above code snippet. added the same case to the question above.

Comment: On my real dataset it is showing as : "null;01/06/1940". it should just be "01/06/1940"

Comment: I’ve added a `filter` step to eliminate both `null` values and empty strings `””`.

Comment: Fabulous, all of my use cases are covered with this. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using lists to store the values:

```
new_df = my_dt.groupby(['last_name', 'first_name']).agg(list).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  last_name first_name           ssn                       dob
0    bhavik    vemulla        [7847]              [09/16/1991]
1  jagarini    yegurla  [0648, 0648]  [01/01/1990, 02/14/1983]
2   mallesh    yamulla  [1234, 4567]  [10/11/1990, 10/11/1990]
```

You can convert to concatenated values with:

```
for col in new_df.set_index(['last_name', 'first_name']).columns:
    new_df[col] = new_df[col].apply(';'.join)
```

Output:

```
  last_name first_name        ssn                    dob
0    bhavik    vemulla       7847             09/16/1991
1  jagarini    yegurla  0648;0648  01/01/1990;02/14/1983
2   mallesh    yamulla  1234;4567  10/11/1990;10/11/1990
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using group_by and agg functions to get the results:

```
my_dt.unique().groupby(['first_name', 'last_name']).agg(pl.col('ssn').apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).